# sort columns of MySql table and show only distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a MySql table :

```
FRUITS                COUNT

apple                   4
mango                   5
banana                  7
apple                   8
coconut                 1
mango                   2
apple                   5
```

I want to show the fruits in descending order of their count.If two fruit names are same,then show the fruit with higher count.So the resulting table should be :

```
FRUITS                COUNT

apple                   8
banana                  7
mango                   5
coconut                 1
```

What should be the query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple `group by` and `order by`.

```
select fruits,
    max(`count`) `count`
from your_table
group by fruits
order by `count` desc;
```

Comment: I think the order by `count` desc is not required.you answer works fine even without order by.

Comment: @Ayan - It is required to ensure the order. For you it may now be showing correctly but at a later point of time it may not.